# How to replace words with another using PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

Please, how can I replace `$example` to `%example%` using PHP? I am a novice.

For example, I have -

```
<textarea>hi %myusername%</textarea>
<input submit>
```

I want, if submitted, the `%myusername%` should change to `$user` and save to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple string replacement method would work fine for this. Take a look at [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) -

> **str_replace** - Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

```
$user = "Lordcash Tugbaski";
$string = "Hi %myusername%";
$searchString = "%myusername%";
$replacement = $user;
$finalString = str_replace($searchString, $replacement, $string);
// Hi Lordcash Tugbaski
```

With regard to saving this data to a database, it really depends on your implementation. All you'll really have to do is place this value into an sql `INSERT` query.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response

pls use
$_SESSION['viewer'];
If user post on shoutbox "welcome %viewer%" and its  submited to database, when reading from database it should change that %viewer% to the current session viewer

Comment: @lor - my answer isn't really meant to be in your production code. I was just giving you an idea of how to use the function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `str_replace($user, "%myusername%", "hi %myusername%");`

You can read all about it in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)